# Solidity Payable function throwing error if it has a loop

Tags: for-loop, solidity

I have a contract with the following payable function

###### Contract Constructor

```
  constructor( address payable _NFT_CONTRACT, address payable _TOKEN_CONTRACT) payable {
    NFT_CONTRACT = IERC721(_NFT_CONTRACT);
    TOKEN_CONTRACT = IERC20(_TOKEN_CONTRACT);
  }
```

###### Function Stake:

```
  function stake(uint256[] calldata  tokenIds, uint256[] calldata  powers) external payable {
    for (uint i = 0; i <= tokenIds.length; i++) {
      uint256 tokenId = tokenIds[i];
      uint256 power = powers[i];

      require(NFT_CONTRACT.ownerOf(tokenId) == msg.sender, "You can only stake your own token");
      require(vault[tokenId].tokenId == 0, "You can only stake once");

      NFT_CONTRACT.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);

      vault[tokenId] = Stake({
        tokenId: tokenId,
        timestamp: block.timestamp,
        owner: msg.sender,
        power: power
      });
      userStacks[msg.sender].push(tokenId);
      hasPaid[tokenId] = 0;
    }
  }
```

> vault, userStacks, and hasPaid are all structs.

```
  struct Stake {
    address owner;
    uint256 tokenId;
    uint256 timestamp;
    uint256 power;
  }
  mapping(uint256 => Stake) public vault;
  mapping(address => uint256[]) public userStacks;
  mapping(uint256 => uint256) public hasPaid;
```

###### The problem:

Function stake works **perfectly fine if I remove the `for loop`**, but, throws this error if I have the loop:

```
revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

I am using `solidity ^0.8.0;`

> I test with arrays such as [1,2], [4,5], for both params.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the input data you're passing to the failing function?

Comment: I test with arrays such as [1,2], [4,5]

Comment: Has the `msg.sender` approved your contract address to operate both token IDs 1 and 2? I.e. invoked the `approve(yourContractAddress, tokenId)` for both token IDs or invoked the `setApprovalForAll(yourContractAddress, true)` on the `NFT_CONTRACT` directly (not through your contract)?

Comment: Yes, I run setApprovalForAll

Comment: If I don't, it rightly throws `'not owner or appreoved' error`